# Can't Deserialize Dictionary<string, List<string>> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value

Tags: c#, json, list, dictionary, deserialization

I've a dictionary.

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>>
```

I serialized this object by using this line;

```
var ss = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objDic, Formatting.Indented);
```

**JSON is Valid!**

```
{
  "keywords a": [
    "keywords analytics,",
    "keywords abstract,",
    "keywords amazon,",
    "keywords anywhere,",
    "keywords adwords,",
    "keywords architecture,",
    "keywords apa,",
    "keywords app store,",
    "keywords and seo,",
    "keywords armor,"
  ],
  "keywords b": [
    "keywords book,",
    "keywords bidding,",
    "keywords broad match,",
    "keywords blog,",
    "keywords business,",
    "keywords book pdf,",
    "keywords by country,",
    "keywords by industry,",
    "keywords bridge,",
    "keywords bidding strategy,"
  ],
  "keywords c": [
    "keywords creator,",
    "reserved keywords c,",
    "keywords c#,",
    "keywords combo list,",
    "keywords cv,",
    "keywords checker,",
    "keywords check,",
    "keywords css,",
    "keywords computer,",
    "keywords consulting resume,"
  ],
  "keywords d": [
    "keywords definition,",
    "keywords density checker,",
    "keywords definition in c,",
    "keywords density,",
    "keywords dublin,",
    "keywords density formula,",
    "keywords digital marketing,",
    "keywords design,",
    "keywords def,",
    "keywords database,"
  ],
  "keywords e": [
    "keywords everywhere,",
    "keywords explorer,",
    "keywords ekleme,",
    "keywords everywhere chrome,",
    "keywords essay,",
    "english keywords,"
  ],
  "keywords f": [
    "keywords finder,",
    "keywords for amazon,",
    "keywords for fluency intermediate pdf,",
    "keywords for fluency pre intermediate pdf,",
    "keywords for youtube,",
    "keywords for slayer leecher,",
    "keywords for seo,",
    "keywords for present perfect,",
    "keywords for resume,",
    "keywords for generator,"
  ],
  "keywords g": [
    "keywords generator,",
    "keywords google,",
    "keywords google seo,",
    "keywords google play,",
    "keywords google analytics,",
    "keywords google adwords tool,",
    "keywords google adwords,",
    "keywords gwent,",
    "keywords good,",
    "keywords google free,"
  ],
  "keywords h": [
    "keywords html,",
    "keywords history,",
    "keywords how to seo,",
    "keywords human resources,",
    "keywords high cpc,",
    "keywords how many,",
    "keywords hearthstone,",
    "keywords how to write,",
    "keywords hq,",
    "keywords halloween,"
  ],
  "keywords i": [
    "keywords io,",
    "keywords international,",
    "keywords in java,",
    "keywords in c,",
    "keywords in python,",
    "keywords imdb,",
    "keywords in html,",
    "keywords in sql,",
    "keywords index medicus,",
    "keywords in seo,"
  ],
  "keywords j": [
    "keywords java,",
    "keywords javascript,",
    "keywords jobs,",
    "keywords journal,",
    "keywords job search,",
    "keywords john patrick leary,",
    "keywords jewelry,",
    "keywords japan,",
    "keywords jeet,",
    "keywords job application,"
  ],
  "keywords k": [
    "keywords kullanımı,",
    "keywords kindle,",
    "keywords kdp,",
    "keywords key words,",
    "keywords kotlin,",
    "keywords keywords tool,",
    "keywords kostenlos finden,",
    "custom keywords katalon,",
    "keywords. try more general keywords,",
    "how are negative keywords different from other keywords,"
  ],
  "keywords l": [
    "keywords list,",
    "keywords latex,",
    "keywords linkedin,",
    "keywords lightroom,",
    "keywords localization,",
    "keywords like as like and is are often used when what type of context clue is used,",
    "keywords leary,",
    "keywords logo,",
    "keywords length seo,",
    "keywords list in java,"
  ],
  "keywords m": [
    "keywords meta,",
    "keywords mesh,",
    "keywords meta tag,",
    "keywords maker,",
    "keywords meaning,",
    "keywords montreal,",
    "keywords marketing,",
    "keywords minecraft,",
    "keywords mysql,",
    "keywords magic the gathering,"
  ],
  "keywords n": [
    "keywords ne demek,",
    "keywords nedir,",
    "keywords nasıl yazılır,",
    "keywords nasıl olmalı,",
    "keywords netflix,",
    "keywords netflix slayer leecher,",
    "keywords neil patel,",
    "keywords nature,",
    "keywords number of searches,",
    "keywords node js,"
  ],
  "keywords o": [
    "keywords or key words,",
    "keywords oluşturucu,",
    "keywords of present simple,",
    "keywords of past continuous,",
    "keywords of present continuous,",
    "keywords of present perfect,",
    "keywords on youtube,",
    "keywords of java,",
    "keywords of c++,",
    "keywords of mysql,"
  ],
  "keywords p": [
    "keywords planner,",
    "keywords present perfect,",
    "keywords past continuous,",
    "keywords present continuous,",
    "keywords present simple,",
    "keywords past simple,",
    "keywords present perfect continuous,",
    "keywords past perfect,",
    "keywords planner tool,",
    "keywords planner google,"
  ],
  "keywords q": [
    "keywords qa,",
    "keywords quality score,",
    "keywords quotes,",
    "keywords questions,",
    "keywords quizlet,",
    "keywords que es,",
    "keywords quality assurance,",
    "keywords que son,",
    "keywords que es en español,",
    "keywords quantitative research,"
  ],
  "keywords r": [
    "keywords research,",
    "keywords resume,",
    "keywords research tool,",
    "keywords ranking,",
    "keywords research google,",
    "keywords research paper,",
    "keywords research free,",
    "keywords revealer,",
    "keywords related to books,",
    "keywords related to bpo,"
  ],
  "keywords s": [
    "keywords studios,",
    "keywords seo,",
    "keywords search,",
    "keywords studios ekşi,",
    "keywords studios katowice,",
    "keywords slayer leecher,",
    "keyword shitter,"
  ],
  "keywords t": [
    "keywords tool,",
    "keywords tool youtube,",
    "keywords türkçe anlamı,",
    "keywords tool google,",
    "keywords tools google,",
    "keywords tool adwords,",
    "keywords tool google adwords,",
    "keywords trend google,",
    "keywords travel,",
    "keywords target audience,"
  ],
  "keywords u": [
    "keywords used in exception handling,",
    "keywords used in java,",
    "keywords used in python,",
    "keywords used in exception handling in c++,",
    "keywords upsc,",
    "keywords usage test,",
    "keywords used in c++,",
    "keywords used,",
    "keywords used in resume,",
    "keywords used by recruiters,"
  ],
  "keywords v": [
    "keywords volume checker,",
    "keywords vs tags,",
    "keywords vs key words,",
    "keywords vs reserved words,",
    "keywords vs search terms,",
    "keywords vision ias,",
    "keywords video,",
    "keywords value,",
    "keywords vs adwords,",
    "keywords vmc,"
  ],
  "keywords w": [
    "keywords wrapper,",
    "keywords with peter and jane,",
    "keywords wordpress,",
    "keywords website,",
    "keywords williams,",
    "keywords wikipedia,",
    "keywords with high cpc,",
    "keywords with ladybird,",
    "keywords with +,",
    "keywords wordstream,"
  ],
  "keywords x": [
    "keywords xing,",
    "keywords xtreme,",
    "keywords xenapp,",
    "keywords xenapp 6.5,",
    "keywords xhtml,",
    "keywords xmp,",
    "keywords xml,",
    "top keywords xing,",
    "adobe bridge keywords xml,",
    "pdf keywords xmp,"
  ],
  "keywords y": [
    "keywords youtube,",
    "keywords yoast seo,",
    "keywords youtube videos,",
    "keywords yoga,",
    "keywords yoast,",
    "keywords yii2,",
    "keywords your searches used,",
    "keywords youtube channel,",
    "keywords youtube tags,",
    "keywords youtube free,"
  ]
}
```

the next line is this.

```
var gg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(ss);
```

In that line im getting error like below.

> Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line
>   1, position 1.

Ok. I tried this also.

```
var gg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(ss);
```

Attention to `List<string>.`

And im getting this error.

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because
>   the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
>   to deserialize from a JSON object.

I want to deserialize the code you saw above back to `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to deserialize the json for a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` into a `string`. Try this instead:

```
var gg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>(ss);
```

**EDIT**

I tested the following and had no issues:

```
public void Test()
{
    test = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
    test.Add("1", new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
    test.Add("2", new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
    test.Add("3", new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
    test.Add("4", new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });
    test.Add("5", new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" });

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(test, Formatting.Indented);
    Dictionary<string, List<string>> deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<string>>>(json);
}
```

Comment: I tried this also but;
Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.

Comment: Hmm, your comment makes it sound like the error your getting is because you're still trying to deserialize to `List<string>` and not `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. I have no problem deserializing a dictionary of lists. See my edit above for a more robust example.

Comment: Ahh. Thank you :)

Comment: If that answered the question, would you mind marking as answered?

Comment: I'm not familiar with stackoverflow. I was looking for it but couldnt found. Now i found where to mark. Thank you again.